# "probsoln" package random default arguments

Tags: probsoln

I'm trying to have random values as the default arguments for a question in probsoln. e.g.:

In the following, a and b are random default arguments.

```
\newproblem[2][{a}{b}]{
     What is #1 multiplied by #2?
}
{
    FPeval(\result}{#1*#2}
    \result
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because

```
 \loadrandomproblems[test]{5}{file}

 \foreachproblem[test]{\item \thisproblem}
```

Will not let me provide arguments unless I use package option usedefaultargs.

So far I have tried variants of:

```
\newproblem[2][{\random{a}{1}{100}}{b}]{
     What is #1 multiplied by #2?
}
{
    FPeval(\result}{#1*#2}
    \result
}
```

but I'm not having any success with that.

Comment: Do you ever use the problem with explicit arguments? If not, perhaps it would be simpler to remove the arguments and define random variables within the problem (as in [this "Random Selection with pgfmath and probsoln" example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/random.shtml#probsoln-rand))

Comment: Thanks for the link, having more flexibility would be better but I guess that solution will do for now.